# Map fragment activity crash in Arbic, android?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, koin

I have map fragment activity and This is the layout file

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llLocationName">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            map:cameraZoom="16"
            map:uiMapToolbar="false"
            map:uiRotateGestures="false"
            map:uiTiltGestures="false" />
```

Java Code I'm using

```
private fun inItGoogleMap() {
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    try {
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.retainInstance = true
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this@HomeActivity)
    }catch (e:Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

Error logcat in Please check once

```
Binary XML file line #42 in com.emojizone:layout/activity_home: Binary XML file line #42 in com.emojizone:layout/activity_home: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42 in com.emojizone:layout/activity_home: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The provided context is not an application context
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.m.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@211816098@21.18.16 (150406-0):0)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@211816098@21.18.16 (150406-0):10)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@211816098@21.18.16 (150406-0):2)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.g.aX(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@211816098@21.18.16 (150406-0):22)
    at dq.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@211816098@21.18.16 (150406-0):4)
```

How can it be solved?

Comment: `The provided context is not an application context`.. So try to `mapFragment.getMapAsync(applicationContext)`

Comment: try {
            binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, layoutRes)
//        }catch (e:Exception){
//            e.printStackTrace()
//        }

@Zain crash this line

when use this Type mismatch: inferred type is Context but OnMapReadyCallback! was expected